# Swiper instance not yet available on window.load

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, elementor

I need to setup the click event on an Elementor carousel widget, which is swiper.js 8 under the hood.
Problem is, depending on the page (same code works elsewhere), not even when window.load executes the swiper instance is available to work with:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    const swiperTarget = jQuery('#dp-neighborhoods .swiper');
    const swiperNeigh = swiperTarget.data('swiper');
    if (swiperNeigh) {
        alert('found it'); //it doesn't
        swiperNeigh.on('click', clickSwiper);
    }
    
    function clickSwiper(swiper, event) {...}
```

I can only get this to work if I call the function from a button, which is not ideal.
A delay (Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time)) doesn't help either.
Would there be another way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this with an observer. Credit to
[Blaize Stewart](https://www.atmosera.com/blog/how-to-implement-the-observer-pattern-with-objects-and-arrays-in-pure-javascript/)

```
function Observer(o, property){
    var _this = this;
    var value = o[property];
    this.observers = [];
    
    this.Observe = function (notifyCallback){
        _this.observers.push(notifyCallback);
    }
    
    Object.defineProperty(o, property, {
        set: function(val){
            _this.value = val;
            for(var i = 0; i < _this.observers.length; i++) _this.observers[i](val);
        },
        get: function(){
            return _this.value;
        }
    });

}

const swiperTarget = document.querySelector('#dp-neighborhoods .swiper'); 
var observer = new Observer(swiperTarget, 'swiper');
observer.Observe(function(newValue){
    const swiperNeigh = newValue;
    if (swiperNeigh) {
        swiperNeigh.on('click', clickSwiper);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the related docs:**
https://developers.elementor.com/expose-swiper-in-elementor/

In my case no matter what it didn't work so I added short timeout (Use fade or something for the slider). Maybe this code is helpful (Added Before close body)

**You should open Github issue related to this

```js
setTimeout(
    function() {
        const imageCarousel = jQuery('#my-id .swiper-container'),
            swiperInstance = imageCarousel.data('swiper');

        swiperInstance.on('afterInit', function() {
            console.log('slide afterInit');
        });

        swiperInstance.on('slideChange', function() {
            console.log('slide changed');
        });

        swiperInstance.on('click', function() {

            if (this.clickedSlide !== undefined) {
                /* do something */
            } /* end if */
        });
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: Thanks for your take, Ezra! Tried different durations to no avail though. Managed with an observer. Cheers.